# Makefile poser to enable multiprocess compilations

Tags: makefile, nmake

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601970/how-do-i-utilise-all-the-cores-for-nmake][1]

This thread talked about nmake makefiles and the fact that 'most' start a separate cl.exe process for every single source file.

Alnitak said,"However most makefiles don't put multiple source files into a single invocation of the compiler - it's far more common for the .cpp files to be compiled to .o files individually."

Well, is it possible to create an nmake makefile which can compile mulitple source files with a single call to cl.exe?

(I'm not too good with makefiles so this might be easy to someone else!)

Answer (score 0):

Well a couple of other links have led me to answer my own question in case anyone is interested...

[Change older makefile system to take advantage of parallel compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865402/change-older-makefile-system-to-take-advantage-of-parallel-compiles)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2x0zs74%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

So the answer is to use so called batch-mode inference rules.